# Baking watermelon

Tags: baking, fruit, watermelon

A while back I saw an article/recipe for baking watermelon -- the watermelon was cut into fillets and baked for a couple hours (IIRC). This was supposed to totally change the texture and give it an interesting and new taste/texture.

I cannot find the recipe now, and cannot find any other recipe similar to it.

This is not a recipe request, but rather a question about the technique: how would one go about baking watermelon (what temp/how long?) and what is the result? In what kinds of dishes would one use baked watermelon? Savory? Sweet?

(Note: I know this question is worded poorly and is slightly ambiguous. any help in rewording and working into a good SE question would be welcome!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually finally found the original source that I read oh-so-long ago. It was an article on Boston.com in which they featured a recipe from the chef at [51 Lincoln](http://www.51lincolnnewton.com/). The recipe can be found [here](http://articles.boston.com/2007-08-08/ae/29237425_1_watermelon-feta-cheese-parchment-paper), and while I can't seem to find the full article (it's behind a paywall now), it's discussed in a blog post [here](http://wwff.wordpress.com/2007/08/10/watermelon-steak/).

In short, you put the watermelon slices in a roasting pan, cover them in cream sherry and butter, cover with parchment paper and aluminum foil, and bake at 350 for 2 and a half hours.

The blog post mentions that the chef serves it with a "confit of tomatoes, eggplant chicharrones, and French feta", and that they typically sell out of the appetizer.

Comment: Very interesting! Not sure I would head towards sherry as a flavoring here, but to each their own. Love the idea of eggplant chicharrones though.

Comment: @Michael yeah, I feel similarly; I remember when I read it that I was intrigued by the technique, but wanted to try something different with it; just thought I'd post it now that I've found it.

Answer (score 6):

Here are a few references for cooked watermelon:

1. (My blog) Herbivoracious, has a recent post showing [how to sear and compress watermelon](http://www.herbivoracious.com/2011/06/seared-watermelon-with-flavors-of-summer-yes-thats-vegetarian-recipe.html).
2. Ideas In Food has a watermelon that is grilled, then cooked sous vide, and then scored and sauteed to [resemble a duck breast](http://blog.ideasinfood.com/ideas_in_food/2011/06/breast-of-watermelon.html).
3. [Modernist Cuisine](http://t.co/OEn3sII) has a recipe for watermelon bulgogi that involves a long dehydration

All of these methods produce quite a change in texture from raw watermelon.

Comment: #2 and #3 were the first two references of which I thought, too; perhaps I should also start reading #1!